# Batch file to remove directories from a base directory according to a text file listing

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a text file with various folder names (one per line):

```
folder2
folder3
```

I'd like to remove all those folders within a directory.

Example directory:

```
folder1
folder2
folder3
folder4
folder5
```

So the [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) would delete `folder2` and `folder3`.

How can I do this?

Comment: This a little hint.You should use 3 bases commandes. For /? , Type /? And RD /? Try to get their help from command prompt and start writing your script !

Comment: Put `RD /s ` before each line.

Comment: @Mark: Nice move. And rename the file to .bat, I would add :)